# VSTACK scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix to one single csr matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, csr

I recently struggled to work with sparse matrices and stacking those to a single matrix.
I used to create multiple csr_matrix objects

```
vec_list = sp.sparse.csr_matrix(my_vec_i) # every vector of shape (1,200)
```

And after `vec_list` consisted of around 100 sparse matrices, I used scipy's (NOT numpy's) sp.vstack function to merge all 100 entries to a csr matrix of shape (100, 200).

Now in my current setting (**python 3.8**) I see a warning that sp.vstack is going to be deprecated, but anyways, not matter if I used numpy's or scipy's vstack functionality, I ended up having an **array of shape (100,1)** where my 200 columns are regarded as 1 csr_matrix entry in the first and only column.

In my old code snippets I could see, that `sp.vstack(vec_list)` created a **sparse crs matrix** of shape (100,200)..
Do I miss anything, does anyone have thoughts on this? I am getting slightly desperate to create my stacked sparse matrix.. thanks all

*Edit:
As you can see below in my comment np.vstack and sp.vstack do not necessarily do the same (in my answer I sad np.vstack twice, but I meant sp.vstack once).  I was using the exact solution (copied) and it returned an error at some point, as no stacking took place.
In order to use sp.stacking,  I stacked non-csr_matrix arrays and then convert this to a csr_matrix. This is not practicable when using huge sets of arrays, but at least I could run through the file without issues.
To address the below answer from Tinu, I was not able to solve it this way, as the result looks like the following - when executing the example code:*

```
>>> np.vstack(vec_list).shape
(100, 1)
>>> sp.vstack(vec_list).shape
(100, 200)
```

Python 3.8.2, Scipy 1.4.1

Comment: It would help us understand your problem if you explicitly show how you define `sp`.  I assume you have done `import scipy as sp`.  If that is the case, then `sp.vstack` is exactly the same function as `numpy.vstack`.  The confusion caused by this duplication is one of the reasons that inclusion of the numpy names in the `scipy` namespace is being deprecated.  For sparse matrices, you want `scipy.sparse.vstack`, as in @Tinu's answer.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I posted a final answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unfortunately not able to see the same result as stated above - using my Python 3.8.3rc1. Copying the code and stacking lead to the following:

```
>>> np.vstack(vec_list).shape # (100, 1)
>>> sp.vstack(vec_list).shape # (100, 1)
```

What I will do to circumvent my problem: I will stack non-csr_matrix arrays and then convert this to a csr_matrix. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately I cannot reproduce your error. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, vstack
import numpy as np

vec_list = []
for i in range(100):
    vec_list.append(csr_matrix(np.random.randint(2,size=(1,200))))
vec_mat = vstack(vec_list)
vec_mat.shape
```

Output:

```
(100, 200)
```

I'm using python 3.8.2 and scipy 1.4.1

Comment: interesting, thanks! Ill have anther look into this

Comment: I cannot explain why we see different results.. 
>>> vec_list = []
>>> for i in range(100):
...     vec_list.append(csr_matrix(np.random.randint(2,size=(1,200))))
...
>>>
>>> a = np.vstack(vec_list)
>>> b = np.vstack(vec_list)
>>> a.shape, b.shape
((100, 1), (100, 1))

Comment: Have a look at the first comment  from @Warren Weckesser under your question. I use the  `scipy.sparse.vstack`, whereas you use `numpy.vstack`, these two functions will not return the same thing for sparse array's.